# How do i access another user's registry portion in win XP

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp

How do i access another user's registry portion in win XP?

how do i access another user's HKey_current_user on my machine, in vb2005 or if someone can recommend a software that can already do it.

Im trying to make a quick registry repair tool to fix a damaged or corrupted user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't, if roaming profiles are enabled the other user's registry on your machine may be incomplete or outdated.

Having said that you can use HKEY_USERS\user-sid

Obviously you have to run as administrator to access other users data.

To translate from SID to name look at this: [How can I convert from a SID to an account name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499053/how-can-i-convert-from-a-sid-to-an-account-name-in-c)

To translate from name to SID look at this: [Unique identifier for user profiles in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787419/unique-identifier-for-user-profiles-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Just an opinion but, usually running remote registry services is troublesome.  I have made the utility to correct the registry entries locally and run the application remotely.  PSExec is a great free utility from Mark and now MS to run your utility after you build and test it.  You can give it a list of systems to hit or it will run it on each system in the domain. Your account does have to have remote execute rights but that's not usually a problem as an admin.  Just be careful when you write the utility to be a bit more cautious as you may wind up running it on machines that you didn't intend to run it on.